# How to pull a branch from remote when you accidentally deleted local branch?

Tags: git, github

I have 3 branches and i have pushed all the 3 branches to remote git [ aka bitbucket am using bb].
I deleted a branch locally now using
    `git branch -d <branch-name>`

I did a git push also .
But now i want all the branches to be present in my local system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you pushed the branches you can create a local branch that is tracking the remote with:

```
git branch --track <local branch name> <remote branch name>
```

Your remote branch names will be something `origin/foo` and you can see the list of them with `git branch -r`

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html

For adding all the remotes in one line you can do the following:

```
git branch -r | egrep -v "(HEAD|master)" | sed -e "s/origin\///" | xargs -I % git branch --track % origin/%
```

This gets a list of all the remote branches except HEAD and master.  Then creates a new local version with the same name that will track the remote.

Comment: Sure. `-- track` will add a local branch corresponding to the remote branch. Suppose i have delete many branches locally, is there a shortcut to add all the remote branches locally ?

Comment: Yes, Here is a script that will do it.  http://technology.mattrude.com/2012/05/git-add-all-branches/

Comment: @user1159517 see updated answer for a single line solution to track all branches

Comment: Why can't I just re-fetch from remote and then check it out locally? (I.e. with `git fetch --all` then `git checkout <deletedbranch>`)?

Comment: @badera because that won't create a new branch. You will end up having your repo in a "detached HEAD state".  In order to keep working, you will need to create a new local copy of the branch in order to make commits and do other work.